# Updating SpringBoot to 2.7.18 caused BeanCreationException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am working on a Spring Boot project created by other people. Recently there's a need to update SpringBoot from 2.5.15 to 2.7.18. However, after updating, I got this error:

*Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.task.TaskExecutorMetricsAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected java.util.concurrent.RunnableScheduledFuture java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.decorateTask(java.lang.Runnable,java.util.concurrent.RunnableScheduledFuture) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util.concurrent" to unnamed module @6d78f375*

The error message does not mention any beans or classes created in the project, so it is very different for me to find where the problem is. The error message was logged by org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext.

Java version is 17.

Search online gave me little information. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the build error by making two changes:

1. Updated spring-cloud-starter to 3.1.8 to be compatible with spring-boot.
2. Excluded TaskExecutorMetricsAutoConfiguration by adding this in the application class: @SpringBootApplication(exclude=TaskExecutorMetricsAutoConfiguration.class)

The real issue causing the exception is as shown in the error message, TaskExecutorMetricsAutoConfiguration. But adding the exclusion reveals the spring-boot and spring-cloud compatibility issue. I am still not sure if it is a good idea to exclude TaskExecutorMetricsAutoConfiguration.